# Could the narrative of Exodus 4:24-26 have happened at another moment in time?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, commentaries, brit-milah, parashas-shemos, shemot-exodus

HaShem commands Moshe to do ׳*all wonders*׳ which HaShem appointed in his hand before Pharaoh once he arrives in Egypt (Shemot 4:21), but despite all wonders - HaShem informs Moshe - Pharaoh will not let the people go because his heart is hardened.

I'm not sure but if 'all wonders' do not only refer to the miracles Moshe had to perform but to the plagues also then maybe the following context should be taken from another perspective;

Because the next couple of lines in which HaShem commands Moshe to tell Pharaoh that *Israël is His first son, His first-born, which he should let go (in order) that Israël may serve Him*.. and ends with the words *and because you refused to let Israël go, behold, I will slay your son, your first-born* seem to refer to the last plague after which the Pharaoh finally sent them away because of the strong hand of HaShem.

If this is true, then the next couple of lines could have happened not on the way from Midyan to Egypt, but occured before or after Moshe went to visit Pharaoh for the last time.

In this case it would be quite logical that the 'Angel of death' came to kill one of the sons of Moshe, because this Angel was on his way to kill all first born children in Egypt who where not part of the covenant. According to Bereshit 17:14 every uncircumcised male (from the Israelites) would be cut off from hus people. And even according to the commands of Pesach if one wants to come and do the Pesach he needs to be circumcised (Shemot 12:48).

Are there any commentaries which point to such a direction?

Comment: Could you clarify what it is you are looking for the commentary to say? That this conversation could have taken place later? Or relate the killing of the first born to the threat to Moshe's son?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות I'm asking both, but let me clearify myself; I noticed many similarities between the conversations between Moshe and HaShem in chapter 3 and 6 for example, which could be fragments of a large story, each with it's own details. "Ein Mukdam U'me'uchar Ba'Torah". I like to take in consideration that it's possible that HaShem foretold his whole plan to Moshe, which is presented to him in fases. But when we read about this the reader is taken back and forth in the story to show what happened and in the meanwhile we are interrupted and some parts of the larger puzzel are represented.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות so to sum things up it's like HaShem tells Moshe: what he needs to do and when, tells him Pharaoh will not lissen, and because Pharaoh will not lissen and ignore the miracles performed, Moshe will have to tell him that if he doesn't release the first born of HaShem that HaShem will strike his first born son. Later on we read more about this when the plagues arrive and the death of the first bornes is actually described.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות In the meanwhile the story - for now - presents us a short narrative about what happened to Moshe his own first born son or son of eight days old, which is important because the 'angel of death' would come to visit the people in Egypt who where not part of the covenant, and as Moshe his son wasn't circumcised according to the command this son could be cut off of his people.